# Read data from an external program into my C#, WPF-program

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to read data from an external [program (click)](http://www.pictureupload.de/originals/pictures/260415165946_read_data_from_external_program.png)(a langenscheidt dictionary), it has thousend of entries in it and I want to read these key values into my WPF application(may be into a grid).

There is a folder. with some human unreadable files("*.prc,*.prc.hdx,*.prc.idx)

```
\Paragon Software\Langenscheidt 7\dictionaries
```

I thought this could be useful, but I am note sure because the folder name leads me to the conclusion, that the data is stored in these files, but these file extensions obviously can not be read by "Kindle" or "AutoCad".

But I don't know where to start.( I found some results in google, but this didn't help me a lot.)

May be you could suggest me some good literature, keywords or good links to my problem ?

By the way, the link for the testversion can be found here [click](http://dl.penreader.com/mswindows/Langenscheidt/7_5/Langenscheidt%20Standard-Worterbuch%20Tschechisch.exe).

Comment: Reverse engineering a file format is difficult, and at the very least may violate the licensing terms of the product you are getting the data from. Try opening the file in a Hex editor and looking for file type markers, just because its one extension doesn't mean its not another type of file. Other than that if its truly proprietary you may find it almost impossible to extract without knowing details from the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

If those are text files (and small enough for you to fit them in memory) then you can just use:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C\Path\To\File.prc");
```

then parse your string however you need to.

There is also:

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C\Path\To\File.prc");
```

if line by line processing is easier to parse